# E-mail function not working on website

Tags: php, email

I have a contact page uploaded at [this](http://www.mdpharma.se/contact.html) site. This URL is working properly, there are no errors or warnings except send mail function is not working.

When I test it in on our testing server it works properly, I can send and receive the mail.

Can you provide any assistance with this please?

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$headers = 'From: info@mdpharma.se' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: info@mdpharma.se' . "\r\n" ;
$message =$_POST['message'];
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

if($_POST['email']){
    mail($to, $subject, $message,null,'-fwebmaster@example.com');
    echo "Mail is successfully sent to you";
} else {
    echo "Mail is not set to you";
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you have a mail service running in the server or that the mail settings in `php.ini` are correct?

Comment: is error_reporting on? have you checked the logs?

Comment: i have no access of this site so not able to check php.ini file , can we resolve this issue without changing in configuration file ?

Comment: tell your hoster to have a look into the error log.

Comment: <?php
  $to      = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  
  $headers = 'From: info@mdpharma.se' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: info@mdpharma.se' . "\r\n" ;
  
  $message =$_POST['message'];
  $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
  
  if($_POST['email']){
   mail($to, $subject, $message,null,'-fwebmaster@example.com');
   echo "Mail is successfully sent to you";
  }
  else
  {
   echo "Mail is not set to you";
  }
?>

Comment: Check the return value of `mail()`, it tells you if the message was accepted for delivery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take help from here http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampledb .
everything is well explained in here. best of luck.

Comment: hey Developer Client give us to one web.config file , and Info from hosting company file can any one tell us how these 2 file are help us to solve this email issue ?

Comment: @gayatri your mail function have problem. use mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: $to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$headers = 'From: info@mdpharma.se' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: info@mdpharma.se' . "\r\n" ;
$message =$_POST['message'];
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

if($_POST['email']){
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    echo "Mail is successfully sent to you";
} else {
    echo "Mail is not set to you";
}